# Is possible to set a memcached expire key when php session expire?

Tags: php, session, caching, memcached

I need to invalidate (expire)some data array from a memcached array when user php session expire , both at the same time . I use memcached for php session too .
Why i simply don't store an array inside $_SESSION ? because all datas are keep/send in http header even in ajax , and thats not the case with an external memcached array .
is possible to set a memcached expire key when php session expire ?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [custom session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) for [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

> When a session is specifically destroyed, PHP will call the destroy
> handler with the session ID.
>
> PHP will call the gc callback from time to time to expire any session
> records according to the set max lifetime of a session. This routine
> should delete all records from persistent storage which were last
> accessed longer than the $lifetime.

In this custom handler you can clear all expired user data from your memcached.

Comment: I should mention that i use memcached for my php session too, i edited .

Comment: Thanks for this update, but it does not essentially to know about session storage, because memcached keys are not directly related to each other. You can try and use custom session handler or just wait until unlogged user data will be evicted